How to Compute the Posterior Distribution of Covariance matrix in a Matrix Normal Model with Inverse Wishart Prior
I am working on a time series model involving Kalman filters and smoothing to estimate state variables $Y_i$. The part of model is structured as follows:
$Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ are iid.
$Y_i \sim \mathcal{MN}(M, \Sigma, V)$.
$\Sigma \sim \text{IW}(\nu, \Xi)$.
The matrix $V$ is known and constant.
As part of a Gibbs sampling process to estimate $Y$ and $\Sigma$, I need to compute the posterior distribution $p(\Sigma | Y_1, \ldots, Y_n)$. While I have managed to derive $p(Y_1, ... ,Y_n|\Sigma)$ using the smoothing equations from the Kalman filter, I am struggling to find $p(\Sigma|Y_1, ... ,Y_n)$.
My Understanding and Attempts:
Conjugacy: I am aware that there is a conjugacy between the Inverse Wishart distribution and the multivariate normal distribution, which suggests that the posterior of $\Sigma$ should also follow an Inverse Wishart distribution.
Marginal Distribution of $Y$: I understand that the marginal $p(Y)$ in the joint distribution $(Y, \Sigma)$ is a
Matrix-T$(M,V,\nu,\Xi)$, but this hasn’t led me to a solution for $p(\Sigma|Y)$.
Specific Question:
How can I compute $p(\Sigma | Y_1, \ldots, Y_n)$? Any pointers or resources would be really helpful.
Please let me know if any other clarification is required. I will make the necessary changes.
